# Can't install Quandl on macOS Sierra

Tags: python, numpy, quandl

For a [sentdex](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfzlCWGWYyIQ0aLC5w48gBQ) tutorial I had to install quandl, but whenever I try to install this python module in python2.7 I get a error:

```
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-
py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
shutil.move(old, new)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
copy2(src, real_dst)
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
copystat(src, dst)
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/26/51wbl41d7hg6gh4vs7zlwchh0000gp/T/pip-HFl5IT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Ive seen this error whenever a installing module needed numpy but already found it so it tried to uninstall it thus resulting in a crash. I have tried "sudo pip install quandl", "pip install quandl", and some more.

Please Help, Thanks!

Comment: Use a virtualenv and install a newer version of numpy. It is always advisable not to play around with the system site-packages.

Comment: Please post the answer as answer and accept it, don't post it into the question putting "SOLVED" into the title…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!!

I tried easy_install and it worked, can't believe that I couldn't find the answer on the internet!!!

I did : "sudo easy_install quandl" And it worked!!!